# Forma de simplificar el siguiente código Python

Tags: python

busco una forma de poder simplificar el siguiente código, conozco una forma de recorrer la lista con `[::]` pero no sé de que manera obtener bloque por bloque `ab` luego `cd`

o si hay otra forma de trabajarlo como con tuplas `[(a,b), (c,d)...]`

```
alfabeto = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
temp = ""
for i in range(0,len(alfabeto),2):
    temp += alfabeto[i]
    temp += alfabeto[i+1]
    print(temp)
    temp = ""
```

salida

```
ab
cd
ef
gh
ij
kl
mn
op
qr
st
uv
wx
yz
```

Comment: Podrías quitar ambos `temp = ""` y cambiar `temp += alfabeto[i]` por `temp = alfabeto [i]`

Comment: Pues si quieres hacerlo como tuplas puedes pasar varias referencias del mismo iterador a `alfabeto` a `zip`, reducirías el proceso a una linea haciendo: `list(zip(*(iter(alfabeto),) * 2))`. Aunque si tu objetivo es simplificar el código, yo lo dejaría como esta. Usar la solución que te mencione antes solo dejara confundido a otra persona que lea tu código, o a ti mismo cuando lo leas en el futuro. La idea de hacerlo asi no es mia, la tome de [esta respuesta en el sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624883/alternative-way-to-split-a-list-into-groups-of-n).

Answer (score 0):

```
alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for i in range(0, len(alfabeto), 2):
    print(alfabeto[i:i+2])
```

No necesitas una variable temporal `temp`, ni concatenar valores. Simplemente extrae de la lista/cadena los elementos que te interesan con la notación  `[::]`.

La notación tiene tres elementos `a:b:c`:

- `a` Es el primer indice (cero, pues partimos del principio).
- `b` Es el último indice. Estamos sacando una tajada de dos elementos, entonces `i+2`.
- `c` es cada cuanto hay que avanzar el índice.

Comment: muchas gracias por ayuda, si algo así quería pero no terminaba de entender la notación, gracias